# Kotlin class file can not run in IntelliJ for JUnit

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit, kotlin

I am an Android and iOS developer. I am new in Kotlin Programming language with IntelliJ. Java class run well with but kotlin class showing err on run time. First it was showing err related JUnit version. I googled and found solution that need to config unit test.

I am using mac so I press Command + Shift + T to configure unit test.

After that when I run the MySecondClass.kt it's showing err like this

```
Information:Kotlin: kotlinc-jvm 1.1.3-2 (JRE 1.8.0_111-b14)
Information:7/10/17, 8:24 PM - Compilation completed with 2 errors and 0 warnings in 2s 85ms
/Users/ehaque/IdeaProjects/My First Kotlin Project/src/MySecondClassTest.kt
Error:(1, 12) Kotlin: Unresolved reference: junit
Error:(7, 10) Kotlin: Unresolved reference: junit
```

My Project Structure is like this:

[image]

What should I do?

Comment: Have you imported JUnit in your kotlin file? It'd help if we could see the file too.

Comment: Are you using Maven, Gradle or any other project/resources/dependencies management tool? You are basically missing a library (JAR file). If you put JUnit (and this is the only one missing) you should be good to go. On the other hand, it can be the `import`s...

Comment: When I press Commend + Shift + T then it shows a dialog. Where it require create test class for that. I follow that and create class MyFirstKotlinClassTest  with import org.junit.Assert*. That's all.

Comment: No I am not using maven or Gradle or any other project management tools. It's a simple java project with Kotlin.

Answer (score 0):

You probably chose the wrong testing library version in the create test dialog.

[image]

It seems you are trying to use JUnit5, but you must have selected JUnit3. The import for the former starts `org.junit.jupiter` whereas the latter starts with `junit`, which you see in the error that you gave in the question.

> `Unresolved reference: junit`